# Fortran cmake with FFTW3

Tags: cmake, fortran, fftw

I'm building CMake file for my Fortran project. But I couldn't get FFTW3 since there's no such thing like

```
find_package(FFTW, ...)
```

like for HDF5.

My code include the module with

```
  include "fftw3.f"
```

What could I do to build a platform-independent CmakeList?

Comment: "What could I do to build a platform-independent CmakeList?" - Write `FindFFTW.cmake` script by yourself, and place it in the your project. You may also try existing `FindFFTW.cmake` scripts, like [this one](https://github.com/ratnania/spipp/blob/master/CMakeModules/FindFFTW.cmake) (found by googling. I haven't check it, but it looks reasonable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course CMake can find FFTW3. Below is a project, where I do exactly that. Also Just go through the output files and look for hints of how to fix your setup / provide environment parameters for `FindFFTW3.cmake` to do the job for you.
https://github.com/kvahed/codeare